# Google vision connection to API without external google DLL

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

How to connect to google cloud vision without using external dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will have to generate JSON request, simple example:

```
            Request req = new Request();
            req.addFeature("DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"); //Add here all the feature types
            req.Image.content = Convert.ToBase64String(qq);//qq is a byte[]
            Requests reqList = new Requests(req);
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqList);
```

Secondly, you need to post simple HTTP request:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key="PLACE_YOURKEY_HERE"");
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                }

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

Memebers of the JSON classes (The methods should be implemented):

```
    class Requests
{
    public List<Request> Request { get; set; }
}
class Request
{
    public Image1 Image { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }

}
public class Feature
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Image1
{
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

Relevant to the topic links

[Google Vision API Document_Text_Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701338/google-vision-api-document-text-detection)

[Feature types](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature#Type)

[Google vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr)